# Pyramid...can't log out of app in windows chrome

Tags: python, google-chrome, pyramid

I have a pyramid app with a login system. Everything works fine on "most" browsers...users can login and logout with no problems. However, in windows chrome, users can login fine but can't logout. When I say they can't logout, if the user refreshes the page, then they are still logged in. No errors are given. Importantly, users can login and logout just fine in Linux chrome and chrome for iPhone (I haven't tested it on any other versions of chrome). I have:

## logout view:

```
@view_config(route_name='logout')
def logout(request):
    headers = forget(request)
    return HTTPFound(location = request.route_url('home'), headers=headers)
```

I've googled but can't find anything that addresses the issue for windows chrome.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I think it is really unlikely that this is actually caused by differences between Chrome on Windows and Chrome on Linux. Could it have to do with existing cookies, or a plugin, or something other? What exact versions and packages are you using?

Comment: On Chromium Linux I have the same bug

Comment: can you see whether the auth-ticket cookie disappears from Chrome when you try to log out?  You can see the cookies in the Chrome developer window under 'Resources' > 'Cookies'.  I don't have any issue with my Pyramid apps in this way.

Comment: Could you post some front-end code of how you're calling this view? I also use a similar logout view and didn't had any problem with chrome.